# Chebyshev variant

Tags: probability

Show that $P(a<X<b)\geq 1-\frac{\sigma^2+(\mu-\frac{a+b}{2})^2}{(\frac{b-a}{2})^2}$ where $X$ is a random variable with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.

I'm having a hard time with this question. I was trying to think of a new variable $X=Y+k$ to so that on $P(a-k<Y<b-k)$ you can just directly apply chebyshev, but I now realize that just shifts everything over so it doesn't help. I was thinking of splitting the interval into $a,\mu+\mu-a$ and $\mu+\mu-a,b$, but then I have no idea what to do with the second interval.

It kind of looks to me like the right side somehow combines the inequality for two different variables, but I have no idea how I would get a variable with variance $(\mu-\frac{a+b}{2})^2$.

Any ideas for how this problem is supposed to be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track with the approach $X=Y+k$. Try setting $k$ to be the *midpoint* of the interval $(a,b)$, so $k:=\frac12(a+b)$, and then the event $\{a<X<b\}$ is the same as the event $\{|Y|<\frac12(b-a)\}$. For brevity write $c:=\frac12(b-a)$.The complement of this last event is then $\{|Y|\ge c\}$, and its probability is
$$
P\left(|Y|\ge c\right)=P(Y^2\ge c^2)\le \frac{E(Y^2)}{c^2}
$$
by [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality). Finish off by computing $E(Y^2)=\operatorname{Var}(Y)+[E(Y)]^2$.

Answer (score 0):

For $a<b$,

$$
\mathsf{P}(a<X<b)=\mathsf{P}(|X-(a+b)/2|<(b-a)/2).
$$